# Insertar a tabla mysql a partir de la segunda fila de archivo excel usando SpreadsheetReader php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una pequeña duda en mi proyecto. Estoy importando datos de un archivo .xlsx a una tabla mysql, todo funciona bien, se carga el archivo a través de un formulario, se lee el contenido de las columnas y se realiza la inserción en la tabla de mi BD, hasta ahí todo está funcional. Lo que quisiera es que la inserción se realizara tomando los datos que estén a partir de la segunda fila (actualmente inserta todos los datos desde la primer fila del archivo).
De manera más gráfica:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir quiero evitar la inserción de la fila subrayada en amarillo, que sería el encabezado de cada columna y hacer la inserción del contenido de la fila 2 en adelante.
Aquí mi código que funciona insertando desde la fila 1.

```
<?php
include('./admin/conn.php');
$usuario = htmlentities($user['s_access'],ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8');

$grupo = $_POST['gruposelect1'];
$materia = $_POST['materiaselect1'];
$unidad = $_POST['unidadselect1'];
$planeacion = "SELECT Id FROM planeacion WHERE Grupo = :grupo AND Iddocente = :docente AND IdMateria = :materia AND Periodo = :periodo AND Año = :year";
$PDOplaneacion = $pdo->prepare($planeacion);
$PDOplaneacion->bindParam(':grupo', $grupo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$PDOplaneacion->bindParam(':docente', $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$PDOplaneacion->bindParam(':materia', $materia, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$PDOplaneacion->bindParam(':periodo', $periodo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$PDOplaneacion->bindParam(':year', $año, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$exito = $PDOplaneacion->execute();
$row = $PDOplaneacion->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$Id=$row['Id'];

$obs="";
$fechaA="0000-00-00";
$firma=0;


require_once('./vendor/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('./vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');


if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{    
$allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];
  
  if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = './subidas/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);
        
        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);
        
        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
        {
            
            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
            
            foreach ($Reader as $Rowi)
            {
          
                $fechaplan = "";
                if(isset($Rowi[0])) {
                    $fechaplan = htmlentities($Rowi[0]);
                }
                
                $tema = "";
                if(isset($Rowi[1])) {
                    $tema = htmlentities($Rowi[1]);
                }
                
                $estrategia = "";
                if(isset($Rowi[2])) {
                    $estrategia = htmlentities($Rowi[2]);
                }
                
                $actividade = "";
                if(isset($Rowi[3])) {
                    $actividade = htmlentities($Rowi[3]);
                }
                
                $actividada = "";
                if(isset($Rowi[4])) {
                    $actividada = htmlentities($Rowi[4]);
                }
                
                
                if (!empty($fechaplan) || !empty($tema) || !empty($estrategia) || !empty($actividade) || !empty($actividada)) {
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO secuenciadidactica (Fecha,IdPlaneacion,Unidad,Tema,Estrategia,ActividadEnsenanza,ActividadAprendizaje,Observaciones,FechaAvance,FirmaAvance) VALUES
                (:Fecha,:IdPlaneacion,:Unidad,:Tema,:Estrategia,:ActividadEnsenanza,:ActividadAprendizaje,:Observaciones,:FechaAvance,:FirmaAvance)';
                $importar = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $importar->bindParam(':Fecha', $fechaplan, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $importar->bindParam(':IdPlaneacion', $Id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $importar->bindParam(':Unidad', $unidad, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $importar->bindParam(':Tema', $tema, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $importar->bindParam(':Estrategia', $estrategia, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $importar->bindParam(':ActividadEnsenanza', $actividade, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $importar->bindParam(':ActividadAprendizaje', $actividada, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $importar->bindParam(':Observaciones', $obs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $importar->bindParam(':FechaAvance', $fechaA, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $importar->bindParam(':FirmaAvance', $firma, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $exito1 = $importar->execute();
 
                
           if (! empty($exito1)) {
                        $type = "card-alert card green";
                        $message = "Planeación importada correctamente.";
                        $icono ="<i class='material-icons'>done</i> <b>Éxito</b></span>";
                        $boton = "<button type='button' class='close white-text' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
                        <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span>";
                    } else {
                        $type = "card-alert card red";
                        $message = "Hubo un problema al importar registros.";
                        $icono ="<i class='material-icons'>close</i> <b>Error</b></span>";
                        $boton = "<button type='button' class='close white-text' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
                        <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span>";
                    }
                }
             }
        
         }
  }
  else
  { 
        $type = "card-alert card red";
        $message = "El archivo que intenta importar es inválido. Por favor vuelva a intentarlo.";
        $icono ="<i class='material-icons'>report_problem</i> <b>Error</b></span>";
        $boton = "<button type='button' class='close white-text' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
        <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span>";
  }
}





?>
```

Estoy usando `SpreadsheetReader`, como comento, está funcionando, la única duda es respecto a la inserción a partir de la fila 2. Agradezco su apoyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo a mi pregunta, por si alguien tiene esa misma duda, la solución es la siguiente:

```
$Reader->ChangeSheet($i);
$primera = true;           

foreach ($Reader as $Rowi)       
{
    // Evitamos la primer línea
    if ($primera){
       $primera=false;
       continue;
    }
}
```

Y listo, podemos insertar saltando la fila 1 del archivo